# golang: how to count number of hops

Tags: algorithm, go, networking, graph-theory

Let's say I have `n` number of nodes.
Each nodes can have at most `m` connections.

In a simulation, I am randomly assigning up to `m` connections to each node.

Now I am wanting to count how many hops there are from any node to any target. For example, if `n=10`, I want to know how many hops there are from n1 to n2, from n1 to n5, n3 to n8 etc. - for all possible connections - and if there even are gaps, i.e. where nodes have no connection.

I have the following code so far, but I heavily doubt it is correct: this just checks direct connections, and also prints just the max if not found.

```
type node struct {
    id int
    connections map[int]*node
}

func calc() {
   for n := 0; n < len(nodes); n++ {
    
    NEXT:
      for target := 0; target < len(nodes); target++ {
        if target == n {
          continue // skip connection to self
        }
        for i := range nodes[n].connections {
          if i == target {
            fmt.Printf("%d to %d has %d hops\n", n, target, count)
            count = 0 
            break NEXT
          }
          count++
        }
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Dijsktra algorithm for hops in shortest path.  Depth or breadth first search (DFS, BFS ) for all paths.

Comment: OSPF and IS-IS use the Dijsktra algorithm for exactly that.

Comment: I'll look these up! Thanks. Look like answers to me, feel free to post your comments as answers?